# What's the naming convention for an object that periodically checks whether something happened?

Tags: naming-conventions

I have an object that mostly sleeps and wakes up periodically to see if something happened, if not it goes to sleep again and so on. How should I call it?

Comment: [poller](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poller)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. It could be. I had also thought of watcher, but maybe there is already a broadly used name for this.

Comment: Why not call it "observer"

Answer (score 2):

I would probably name it XxxWatchService - ofcourse xxx is a Subject You are watching.

In this case 'observer' is rather bad name because it is name From observer pattern and than it should have other architecture otherwise it could misslead someone who would read this name.